# Dual booting Lubuntu with Windows 8

Tags: dual-boot, lubuntu, windows-8, bootloader

I've got an older laptop (HP G62) that has Windows 8 as its primary OS and I want to dual boot it with Lubuntu. It does not come with Secure Boot,m nor does it come with UEFI.

I've been looking at [this guide](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/10/dual-booting-windows-7-and-ubuntu-12-10-quantal-quetzal/) and it says that I need to:

1. Shrink the Windows partition.
2. Create a primary ext4 partition (using the free space) with the mount point set to /
3. Create a swap (logical) partition.

   Note: For me it would be 6GB.
4. Choose the Lubuntu partition and click *Install Now*.

I am 100% aware that the link that I provided does talk about Windows 7, but I haven't seen any valid guide on how to dual boot Lubuntu with Windows 8 on a laptop or PC without UEFI.

I have two questions:

1. Will GRUB replace my Windows 8 bootloader?

   [image: Choose an operating system]
2. Should I make the main partition (`/`) primary?

I know this guide is for Ubuntu, but since they're pretty much the same I though this guide would work for Lubuntu users as well.

Comment: That link is for dual-booting Win 7 and *buntu. Win 8 maybe quite different. Please use the search feature of Ask Ubuntu to find very similar questions and their answers. Providing details of your PC and how you installed Windows 8 may also be helpful.

Comment: I am aware that the link is for Windows 7 but I can only find guides for Windows 8 that include secure boot. My laptop originally came with Windows 7 and I upgraded it to 8.

I know there are some differences between the two, but it can't be that different...

Comment: Use Windows to shrink NTFS partition, and main difference with Windows 8 or 10 is the fast start up or always on hibernation. Otherwise Windows 8 (or 10) in BIOS mode is like Windows 7 when in BIOS boot mode. http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation Do have or make Windows repair flash drive and have Ubuntu live installer always available. Windows may turn fast start back on with updates or re-install its boot loader. And when Windows breaks, grub will not boot it. You then need to temporaily restore Windows boot loader & use its repairs.

Answer (score 1):

1. Grub will replace your boot-loader and it will look like a standard Linux GRUB menu. You can however make Linux OR Windows as your default after successfully installing Linux.
2. Let Ubuntu installer handle partitioning. You do not need to create partitions manually before installation. Ubuntu installer will provide visual tool where you simply slide and adjust the space desired to Linux and Windows. The gui partition tool/installer will handle the rest and update GRUB boot menu. You can not have the Windows boot-loader BUT it will boot to both OS just fine.